# Can't figure out how i misconfigurated my docker-compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I followed multiple guides and tutorials.

This is my docker-compose file.

It gives the following error,

`services.mysql.environment.volumes contains ["mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql"], which is an invalid type, it should be a string, number, or a null`

And it creates a volume with the name _volumename?

I just don't seem to get the mistake i made.

```
version : '3'
services:
  mysql:
    container_name: auth_db
    restart: always
    image: mysql:latest
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: supersecret
      MYSQL_DATABASE: name
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASS: supersecret2
      volumes:
        - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
      ports:
        - 3306:3306

  auth-service:
    build: ./authservice
    volumes:
      - ./authservice:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - 5000:5000

volumes:
  mysql_data:
```

Some more information.

If i change the volume line to 
`volumes:                                                                                                          "- mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql"`

The docker-compose file will compile but 
`docker volume ls` gives this output

```
local               4fa81a11596c2b67c2bb799d54afc6009ebcd82fcd10acae53a5aeefd005fd36
local               8636df909155569e8ebf0649f4c192616d0b6778d5eb7932b1f9542db55a07d8
local               832739c89f3b33ad0a1974ad7dc2ee9342373f904af3b2be5934331bae50b5e6
local               e5bb4a869f54ce3200d5a1fe129bc1f8ee46515cf03d9dd2ff327430d792117b
local               e35a38127fcb07702a58133883a021aa56c4aad6c439d254f32a119ad380d808
local               hell_mysql_data
```

My current dir where the docker-compose file is located is HELL that why i think it got the prefix from

Comment: Did you tried `./mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql`?

Comment: I didn't try that. But all the resources give me the indication that this is not necessary. For example this one https://severalnines.com/blog/mysql-docker-composing-stack. I get the idea that this should work. But i'm missing something obivious

Comment: - "mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql", your identation seems to be wrong too. Volumes and Ports should be in the same level as environment, image, restart and container.

Comment: have you tried with "- mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql"  ? I think justin is right to point out that

Comment: I tried reformating the whole file and that also didn't worked. It seems to complain about the volume mysql_data only the weird thing is if i remove the space between the - and volume name the docker-compose file while compile.

Comment: Okey the solution that worked for me is to include the - in the " " so that line will look the following ``volumes:                                                                                          
 "- mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql"     `` This doesn't seem right to me as i haven't seen this notation before.

Comment: and the volumes created also don't reverence to the volume created by the docker file `` local               hell_hell_mysqldata
local               hell_mysql_data `` ( my dir file is hell)  sorry for the bad format markup isn't working well. ps this is the output of docker volume ls

Comment: `volumes:` and `ports:` are indented one level too far.  (Notice the word “environment” in the error message, you shouldn’t expect that.)

Comment: Okey didn't notice that will try it out now. I tottaly missed that !

Comment: Thanks that seems to be the solution. Should wear my glases more often.

Comment: @FábioCorreia Even when u told it i still didn't notice thanks everybody for the response :D

Comment: But the problem with the volume name still seems to persist. Does anybody have experience with that?

Comment: When you create a compose file, as default behavior, it will concatenate folder_volume.

That's the docker default name for "projects" where the name is not specified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is regarding indentation, volumes and ports must be top level first inside your service definition, as follows:

```
version : '3'
services:
    mysql:
      container_name: auth_db
      restart: always
      image: mysql:latest
      environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: supersecret
        MYSQL_DATABASE: name
        MYSQL_USER: user
        MYSQL_PASS: supersecret2
      volumes:
        - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
      ports:
        - 3306:3306

    auth-service:
      build: ./authservice
      volumes:
        - ./authservice:/usr/src/app
      ports:
        - 5000:5000

volumes:
    mysql_data:
```